# Blocking users using Chrome DevTool

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, emulation, google-chrome-devtools

I have a mobile web application which collects lot of data from the device like the users latitude and longitude, information about device operating system etc., I need to block the users who are using mobile emulators from sending false data to the system.

I need a way to find if the user is using any emulators.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot block features on the browser-client. This is sandboxed away from the JavaScript execution engine

Comment: At least is there a way to know if a user is using DevTools?

Comment: Users can send whatever you want to your system, and you can help that, no matter what. You can do some server filtering to look at their request, but they can really change that. There is no easy solution; it is the same with game hacking. They will still send that they are legit ;)